# Getting text of all the elements inside a div using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the [link](https://foodkoreadubai.com/products/teazen-organic-barley-sprout-powder-2g-x-10-sticks#description). I am trying to scrape the entire description texts. It is all under a div class called "station-tabs-content-inner". But some texts are under the lists tag and some are under the p tag with no specific class name. Can someone help me to get all the texts inside this div, regardless of their tags?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the HTML? also, please include what you have already tried

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an interesting HTML source.

If you inspect the source, you'll see that the data is also available in JSON format:

[image]

So, grab the data from there:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://foodkoreadubai.com/products/teazen-organic-barley-sprout-powder-2g-x-10-sticks#description"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

content = soup.find("script", id="ProductJson-product-template").string

json_data = json.loads(content)["description"]

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(json_data, "html.parser")

for tag in soup2.select("ul:nth-of-type(1) span, p, ul:nth-of-type(2) li"):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n\n"))
```

Prints:

```
Soft, Delicious Barley Sprout Powder: TEAZEN sprout barley powder is a young barley leaf grown about 25cm after germination. Produced by hygienic automated equipment and crushed by ultra fine grinder It is an excellent green product
Korean Organic Barley Sprout Powder: Signed an MOU supply of barley sprout with Haenam-gun, Korea. We produce TEAZEN sprouted barley powder rich in dietary fiber and chlorophyll by grinding the sprouted barley carefully grown in the clean and beautiful Haenam-gun without squeezing it.
Individual Stick Packaging: Hygienic, easy-to-store stick type
Consume in a variety of ways according to your taste: Put 1 barley sprout powder stick into milk (soy milk) or 250ml of mineral water and enjoy. You can enjoy by adding 1 barley sprout powder stick to 100ml of yogurt, or sprinkle it on salads!
Contains Chlorophyll and Dietary Fiber. Barley Sprout contains 20 times more dietary fiber than sweet potato.
Chlorophyll’s reputation as a health and wellness supplement predates the recent TikTok-fueled interest by decades. It has long been touted for a wide range of health benefits, including:
Cancer prevention.
Healing wounds.
Skin care and acne treatment.
Weight loss.
Controlling body odor.
Relieving constipation and gas.
Boosting energy.
```

---

The CSS Selector selects:

- A `span` element that is a descendant of the first `ul` element.
- All `p`  elements on the page.
- `li`  elements that are descendants of the second `ul` element.

See the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) and [Selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list) (`,`) CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://foodkoreadubai.com/products/teazen-organic-barley-sprout-powder-2g-x-10-sticks"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

text = []
for tag in soup.select_one(".description > div").find_all(recursive=False):
    h6 = tag.find_previous("h6")
    if not h6 or "Description" not in h6.text or tag.name == "h6":
        continue
    text.append(tag.text)

print("\n".join(text).strip())
```

Prints:

```
Soft, Delicious Barley Sprout Powder: TEAZEN sprout barley powder is a young barley leaf grown about 25cm after germination. Produced by hygienic automated equipment and crushed by ultra fine grinder It is an excellent green product
Korean Organic Barley Sprout Powder: Signed an MOU supply of barley sprout with Haenam-gun, Korea. We produce TEAZEN sprouted barley powder rich in dietary fiber and chlorophyll by grinding the sprouted barley carefully grown in the clean and beautiful Haenam-gun without squeezing it.
Individual Stick Packaging: Hygienic, easy-to-store stick type
Consume in a variety of ways according to your taste: Put 1 barley sprout powder stick into milk (soy milk) or 250ml of mineral water and enjoy. You can enjoy by adding 1 barley sprout powder stick to 100ml of yogurt, or sprinkle it on salads!
Contains Chlorophyll and Dietary Fiber. Barley Sprout contains 20 times more dietary fiber than sweet potato.

Chlorophyll’s reputation as a health and wellness supplement predates the recent TikTok-fueled interest by decades. It has long been touted for a wide range of health benefits, including:

Cancer prevention.
Healing wounds.
Skin care and acne treatment.
Weight loss.
Controlling body odor.
Relieving constipation and gas.
Boosting energy.
```

Comment: while I do like your answers, there is some extra HTML being printed out in your code, not what the OP wanted.

Comment: See my below answer

Comment: @MendelG Yep, you're right. I've modified my answer.